# É possível passar um vetor como parâmetro no Visualg?

Tags: visualg

É possível passar um vetor como parâmetro no Visualg? Se sim, quais métodos devem ser utilizados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível passar um vetor como parâmetro para uma função uma vez que o vetor é um dado estruturado e não um tipo de dado válido.

Segundo o [manual do visualG 3.0](https://manual.visualg3.com.br/doku.php?id=manual) os tipos de dados válidos são somente:

- Inteiro
- Real
- Lógico
- Caractere

Ao se tentar declarar uma função com a estrutura vetor, o programa retorna a mensagem de *tipo de dado "VETOR" não reconhecida*, pois de fato, par ao visualG não é um tipo de dado.
Bem como ao tentar realizar a chama de um vetor, passando a estrutura como argumento, é retornado um erro de *"esperava encontrar um ["*.

Caso a função não altere o tamanho original do vetor, podes utilizar um vetor temporário global e manipular pela função, mas não conseguirás passá-lo por parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Para declarar um vetor no VisualG use  `vet: vetor [1..10] de real`. Depois, iterar com ele use `vet[1]`, por exemplo.

Note que o número total de variáveis suportado pelo VisuAlg é 500 e cada elemento de um vetor é contado individualmente. Ou seja, se você declarar 4 variáveis do tipo int só pode ter um vetor com 495 posições, no máximo.

Aqui você confere o manual do [VisualG](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~bosco.sobral/ensino/ine5201/Visualg2_manual.pdf) ou [aqui para uma versão com índice](http://eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/refer.htm).